# user customized notification time from date picker in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, datepicker, notifications, swiftui, timepicker

So this is what I have so far, a picker displaying hours and minutes, and a notification that goes out every day at 2pm, I am trying to bind them so that the user can manually choose the time they would like the notification to go off, with time translated into 24 hours format and placed into ->

```
 dateComponents.hour = 14
 dateComponents.minute = 00
```

this is my picker code where I display time only:

```
import UserNotifications
import SwiftUI

struct Calendar: View {

    @State private var didTap:Bool = false
    @State var alert = false
    @State private var currentDate = Date()
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    @State private var isdateshowing = false
    @State private var textfield = ""

   var body: some View {

    List {



        Section {
             TextField("Choose at when you would like to be reminded", text: $textfield, onEditingChanged: {
                 edit in

                 if edit {
                     self.isdateshowing = true
                 } else {
                     self.isdateshowing = false
                 }
             })
        if isdateshowing {

            DatePicker(selection: .constant(Date()), displayedComponents: .hourAndMinute, label: { Text("Time") })

    }

        }
```

and this is a button that both request the permission to send daily notifications and enables it,

```
        Section {
Button(action: {
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        .requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) { (status, _) in
    if status{

        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        content.title = "It Is Time!"
        content.body = "LETS DO THIS!"
         content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default

        var dateComponents = DateComponents()
        dateComponents.hour = 14
            dateComponents.minute = 00


     //   let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 5, repeats: false)

        let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponents, repeats: true)
        let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "noti", content: content, trigger: trigger)
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request, withCompletionHandler: nil)
        return
    }
    self.alert.toggle()

    }
}) {
    Text("Press to Enable Daily Notifications")

    }.alert(isPresented: $alert) {
            return Alert(title: Text("Please Enable Notification Access from Settings Pannel !!"))
                }
            }



        }
    }
}
struct Calendar_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Calendar()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try something like this (untested):

in your Calendar View add:

```
@State var selectedTime = Date()
```

and change:

```
DatePicker(selection: self.$selectedTime), displayedComponents: .hourAndMinute, label: { Text("Time") })
```

Edit

Without knowing what your are really trying to achieve, my suggestion is; try to break your code into individual elements, such as:

```
func sendNotification() {
    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = "It Is Time!"
    content.body = "LETS DO THIS!"
    content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default

    if let thisHour = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour], from: Date()).hour,
        let selectedHour = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour], from: self.selectedTime).hour {
        // Note, this sends the notification at the selectedHour or later
        if (thisHour >= selectedHour) {
            var dateComponents = DateComponents()
            dateComponents.hour = selectedHour
            dateComponents.minute = 0

            let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponents, repeats: true)
            let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "noti", content: content, trigger: trigger)
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request, withCompletionHandler: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

then in the section where you request the permission:

```
    Section {
        Button(action: {
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) { (status, _) in
                if status {
                    self.sendNotification()
                } else {
                    self.alert.toggle()
                }
            }
        }) {
            Text("Press to Enable Daily Notifications")
        }.alert(isPresented: $alert) {
            Alert(title: Text("Please Enable Notification Access from Settings Pannel !!"))
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for you suggestion and sorry to bother you but I am very new to SwiftUI. I am really not sure where to place the last part in the notification section, it keeps giving me errors ( types hour & current have no members in the Code). What would you do to fix it?

Comment: I've updated my answer. I don't know why you are having errors in with hour & current. You would need to show your code.